# Issue with javascript href

Tags: javascript, html

I have a jsp page in struts 1.2 which has 2 functionalities. Print pdf and submit form.
 Print pdf will open a new window and display a pdf generated with the field values in the page.
 Submit form should navigate to confirmation page in the same window and save values in db. 
Here are the part of code for it.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:printPDF();" target="_blank"><img src="/images/buttons/ButtonPrint.gif" border="0" alt="Print" ></a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:submitContinue();"><img src="/images/buttons/ButtonSubmit.gif" border="0" alt="Submit" ></a>
```

Here are the corresponding javascript methods.

```
function submitContinue()
{
    document.forms[0].action = "/provider/requestSubmitted.do?method=processUpload";
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}

function printPDF()
{
    document.forms[0].action = "/provider/requestSubmitted.do?method=printPDF";
    document.forms[0].target="new";
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
```

}

These functionalities works fine separately. But if I click on print and then on submit, the next page(confirmation page) opens in a new tab. It should be in the same window. Please help !!

Comment: remove target="_blank"

Comment: Why this line in printPDF()?  ->   document.forms[0].target="new";

Comment: @Manish: Its to open the pdf in a new window

Comment: @rajeshkakawat: Tried. But didn't work. But I don't have a target attribute for submit anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jijo,

you have a script to submit a form, in your form object to submit has a target attribute, when the target has value **new** or **xxx** (tab name) this works fine, you must remove the target value from your form object.

```
 function submitContinue()  
 {
    document.forms[0].action = "/provider/requestSubmitted.do?method=processUpload";
    document.forms[0].target="_self";
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}  
 function printPDF()
 {
     document.forms[0].action = "/provider/requestSubmitted.do?method=printPDF";
     document.forms[0].target="pdf";
     document.forms[0].submit();
     return true; 
 }
```

if you have

```
 <form action="xxx" **target="yyy"**
```

you must remove again target="yyy"

The documentation about target attribute is

```
target values      Description
  _blank            Specifies where to display the response that is 
  _self
  _parent
  _top
```

Comment: It worked fine. Thanks !! I've another issue now. In IE8, the PDF link which gets opened in new window displays a "Page Cannot be Found" page first. I have to refresh the page to display the pdf. Any idea why is it so??

Comment: only in IE8 have you this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
function submitContinue()
{
    document.forms[0].action = "/provider/requestSubmitted.do?method=processUpload";
    document.forms[0].target=self; <-------HERE
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}
```

when you use printPDF the form target is set to "new", and if you don't refresh the page or reset it to "self" (or null) that form will open a new window on every submit.

Comment: Tried. But didn't work. When I click on submit, I guess it first opens a window then only going through the javascript function. Should I try refreshing the page after every time I click on print ?

Comment: no, the form is executed on "submit()" so the new windows will open on "submit()" too. check if your page has not been cached, see the source in the browser and check for this change to be present